# Magento dashboard total sales price is not updating still on 0.-

Tags: magento, dashboard

The magento dashboard sales total is not updating and is still on 0,- after several orders.
Is this a known issue or does anyone know how to fix this?

I have searched the whole magento forums and online but cannot find anything regarding this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should refresh statistics I guess.